# Trouble installing libaio-dev

Tags: installation, package, debian, apt

This is error code I get. I'm using mint Debian edition

apt-get install libaio-dev

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 983 not upgraded.
18 not fully installed or removed.
N    eed to get 0 B/25.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 143 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 170878 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libaio-dev (from .../libaio-dev_0.3.109-2_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libaio-dev_0.3.109-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man2/io_getevents.2.gz', which is also in package manpages-dev 3.28-1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libaio-dev_0.3.109-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove manpages-dev
sudo apt-get install libaio-dev manpages-dev
```